# OpenCV/Python: VideoCapture can't read the last frame correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video

I'm using openCv and python 2.7.

I'm trying to read a video but the last frame has no type and I can't show it.

My video has 16 frames and frame rate is 4fps.

Printing the types of the frames I get:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
...
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'NoneType'>
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, fi
le C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\
window.cpp, line 271
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3_1.py", line 113, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\high
gui\src\window.cpp:271: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function
cv::imshow
```

My code is:

```
cap_2 = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')
while(cap_2.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap_2.read()

    print type(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap_2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: That's not the last frame, at that point you've already gone past the end. You don't test `ret` to see whether the read succeeded, nor do you test `frame` for not being empty, before you pass it to `imshow`. Furthermore, `VideoCapture::isOpened()` returns `True` as long as the video is open. Reading all the frames will not affect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @DanMašek.

The problem is that I did not test `ret` to see where the read succeeded. So the file was open but there was no new frame to read and as a result I got `NoneType Error`.

Thus, my final correct code is:

```
cap_2 = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')
while(cap_2.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap_2.read()

    if ret == true:
        print type(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
             break

cap_2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```